# Example Oraclize files return 0: string: when called in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, oraclize

I want to use Oraclize in Remix, to test it. I'm too stupid to use their examples.
How can I make this work?
From their [Github](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/YoutubeViews.sol) I took the YouTube-Views code and copied it into Remix

```
 pragma solidity >= 0.5.0 < 0.6.0;

import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract YoutubeViews is usingOraclize {

string public viewsCount;

event LogYoutubeViewCount(string views);
event LogNewOraclizeQuery(string description);

constructor()
    public
{
    update(); // Update views on contract creation...
}

function __callback(
    bytes32 _myid,
    string memory _result
)
    public
{
    require(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
    viewsCount = _result;
    emit LogYoutubeViewCount(viewsCount);
    // Do something with viewsCount, like tipping the author if viewsCount > X?
}

function update()
    public
    payable
{
    emit LogNewOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer...");
    oraclize_query("URL", 'html(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0).xpath(//*[contains(@class, "watch-view-count")]/text())');
}
}
```

When I use the viewCount it returns:

0: string:

This happens with all the other examples aswell.
With WolframAlpha eg. I also get the following error:

transact to WolframAlpha.update errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you don't see the answer like a normal result in Remix:

You have to go under settings and open the Oraclize plug in.

If you then deploy the contract and or click update, you get the result shown in the plug in.